# Search either first name or last name in datatable and jQuery

Tags: javascript, datatables

A friend asked for my help regarding their datable. the datatable displays a list of users with a real-time search box. They are using the search box for searching the first name. If they want to change the way they search like from first name to Last name, they just change the array number. here's the code I am talking about,

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }
}
</script>
```

The table looks like this

[image]

so like I said if they want to change the searching from last name to first name, they just update this line, **td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2];** to **td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[3];** so I figured that the number in the array is the column arrangement, I am not a jQuery person so I tried something like **td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2][3];** but obviously it doesn't work. Just trying my luck maybe this is something you knew or encountered before? what is the best action on this? What we want to achieve is to be able to search either the first name or the last name.

Comment: just for the sake of records that's vanilla js not jquery. and if you want to keep the same exact logic and just add a condition that will check if the other column matches, just add a new variable initialization `td2 = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[3];` and inside the if condition add `|| td2.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1`. You can remove the `if(td)`.

Comment: ahhh ok so that's Vanilla Js... Thanks @DiegoD i'll try that

Comment: I was very minimalistic in my comment.. please comment here if you have problems understanding my suggestion. When I said add that line in the if condition I meant to use an `or` condition .. so that it will style the row as visible both if the first column `or` the second column match with the filter

Comment: by the way you showed yourself surprised of something pretty obvious. I wonder how far you could understand the suggestion given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how to show each table row if any of the ***Last Name*** or ***First Name*** do match with the filter condition.

The key is having an or condition in the if statement that decides to style the row as visible or not.

I followed the same header as shown in the picture you shared. To say the truth, according to the visible cells, the index for ***Last Name*** and ***First Name*** are respectively `1` and `2` not as mentioned in the question `2` and `3`.

```js
function filter() {
  var input, filter, table, tableBody, tr, td, i;

  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");

  //here I'm limiting the search for tr elements inside the tbody instead of the whole table
  //..to exclude the header from the operation
  tableBody = table.querySelector('tbody');
  tr = tableBody.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {

    //here I'm retrieving the cells corresponding to the LastName and FirstName
    tdLastName = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
    tdFirstName = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2];

    //here I'm using the optional chain operator (?)
    //...to access those properties only if the object is not undefined -it avoids using if(td)
    lastName = tdLastName?.textContent.toUpperCase();
    firstName = tdFirstName?.textContent.toUpperCase();
    
    if (lastName?.indexOf(filter) > -1 || firstName?.indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      tr[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      tr[i].style.display = "none";
    }

  }
}
```

```css
.search-container {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

th {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="search-container">
    <label for="myInput">Search by Last Name or First Name Here:</label>
    <input type="text" id="myInput">
    <button onclick="filter();">Filter</button>
  </div>

  <table id="myTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>DOB</th>
        <th>Therapist</th>
        <th>Co-Pay</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>From Date</th>
        <th>To Date</th>
        <th>Report Due</th>
        <th>Date Added</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Active</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>01/01/1990</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td>$20</td>
        <td>Main Office</td>
        <td>02/01/2022</td>
        <td>02/28/2022</td>
        <td>03/01/2022</td>
        <td>01/01/2022</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Inactive</td>
        <td>Williams</td>
        <td>James</td>
        <td>12/14/2022</td>
        <td>Dr. Garcia</td>
        <td>$67</td>
        <td>Lakeside</td>
        <td>08/25/2022</td>
        <td>05/20/2021</td>
        <td>05/17/2020</td>
        <td>08/09/2022</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Active</td>
        <td>Williams</td>
        <td>Jennifer</td>
        <td>01/26/2022</td>
        <td>Dr. Davis</td>
        <td>$28</td>
        <td>Downtown</td>
        <td>12/08/2020</td>
        <td>04/04/2021</td>
        <td>08/04/2022</td>
        <td>06/05/2021</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Inactive</td>
        <td>Johnson</td>
        <td>James</td>
        <td>03/05/2022</td>
        <td>Dr. Garcia</td>
        <td>$44</td>
        <td>Northside</td>
        <td>08/23/2021</td>
        <td>03/17/2021</td>
        <td>08/27/2021</td>
        <td>10/07/2020</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Pending</td>
        <td>Williams</td>
        <td>James</td>
        <td>02/19/2022</td>
        <td>Dr. Miller</td>
        <td>$71</td>
        <td>Suburb</td>
        <td>01/19/2022</td>
        <td>07/16/2021</td>
        <td>07/13/2022</td>
        <td>09/30/2022</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Pending</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>03/23/2020</td>
        <td>Dr. Roberts</td>
        <td>$14</td>
        <td>Lakeside</td>
        <td>07/08/2021</td>
        <td>01/30/2022</td>
        <td>10/17/2020</td>
        <td>10/09/2021</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Inactive</td>
        <td>Jones</td>
        <td>James</td>
        <td>10/22/2022</td>
        <td>Dr. Wilson</td>
        <td>$34</td>
        <td>Northside</td>
        <td>07/05/2021</td>
        <td>08/14/2020</td>
        <td>10/12/2020</td>
        <td>10/19/2021</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Pending</td>
        <td>Johnson</td>
        <td>Jennifer</td>
        <td>06/13/2020</td>
        <td>Dr. Wilson</td>
        <td>$60</td>
        <td>Suburb</td>
        <td>07/27/2022</td>
        <td>01/30/2022</td>
        <td>01/01/2021</td>
        <td>10/29/2022</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Inactive</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td>Jennifer</td>
        <td>03/03/2022</td>
        <td>Dr. Wilson</td>
        <td>$100</td>
        <td>Main Office</td>
        <td>06/28/2022</td>
        <td>11/27/2020</td>
        <td>11/15/2020</td>
        <td>03/28/2022</td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>

</body>
```

Comment: With this, we can add additional columns to search if they want to. Thank you!